# IF Statement for a Formula Requiring Multiple Conditions on Microsoft Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a population of figures for which i have calculated the standard deviation on as well as the value of one standard, two standard, and three standard deviations away from the mean. I want to write an IF statement that would return "one standard deviation", "two standard deviation", "three standard deviation" or "NA" depending on where a value in my population of figures falls under. An excerpt of the data is as shown below:

[image]

I have a rudimentary understanding of excel so the IF statement i used consists of the below formula

```
=IF(B2>J$2,"One SD",IF(B2>K$2,"Two SD",IF(B2>L$2,"Three SD", "NA")))
```

However if i run this formula in the excerpt for example, the formula will return "One SD" instead of "Three SD" because the value in the population is larger than the first argument. I need a way for it to pick the argument it is precisely greater than or less than instead of the first condition it meets.

Comment: Flip the logic. Check for Three SD first, then Two SD, then One SD.

Comment: Or better divide (abs(value)-mean)/std_dev and round to integer according to taste. The if you want you can use conditional formatting to highlight those which  you want to stand out. You could convert this value into text if you wanted by indexing.

Comment: @BigBen comment is probably best here, but another option is instead of just checking `B2>J$2`, check `AND(B2>J$2,B2<K$2)`